# Apache redirect to the exact Directory clean URL

Tags: php, apache

On my website I want to make the URL looks more clean so now it looks like This

```
http://mywebsite.com/application/public/index.php
```

I want to see something cleaner just index controllers and params like this

```
http://mywebsite.com/index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your Application path from apache Like so

```
<Directory /yousitefolders/application/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
</Directory>
```

OR  by just creating a `.htaccess` on your website folder normally public_html and write this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ application/public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a "`.htaccess`" file on the root directory (public_html/) and make a redirection rule like this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*) application/public/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```